# Change JavaFx chart origin

Tags: javafx, linechart

I created a JavaFX lineChart but when the values are too close I get something like : [image: chart issue]

instead of :

[image: normal chart]

How can I change the origin of the JavaFX chart dynamycally ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The y axis and x axis are [NumberAxis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html) instances.  You can `setLowerBound` and `setUpperBound` to change the range of the axes. `setForceZeroInRange` could also be interesting.

Comment: I can't agree more ;) xAxis = new NumberAxis(); xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false); saved my day.